# 指導に当たる meaning? To teach someone or to be taught by someone

Tags: meaning

I was reading a passage about the life of Hideyo Noguchi and found this phrase. The biography said

> 39ー51歳
> 黄熱病の研究のため、中・南米に渡り、アフリカにも行く。現地の医師の指導に当たる。

My question is, does that mean that Hideyo taught and instructed the local physicians in Africa or was he taught by those locals?

Comment: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=の指導に当たる

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「～～に当{あ}たる」 here means "to be in charge of (a task)", "to take on (a job)", etc.

Thus, 「現地{げんち}の医師{いし}の指導{しどう}に当たる。」 means:

"***He was in charge of training local doctors***."